# for await gives SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word inside a async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, azure-blob-storage

Here is my code that throws the exception. Not able to figure out why it says 'Unexpected reserved word'. main() function is an async type. It isn't complaining for above line of code.

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
async function main() {
    try {
        const blobServiceClient = await BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString('some string');
        let i = 1;
        const result = await blobServiceClient.listContainers();
        for await (const container of result) {
            console.log(`Container ${i++}: ${container.name}`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: Probably the JavaScript engine does not support the `for await` syntax. Question is whether you really need it, since `result` is not an async iterable

Comment: listContainer returns PagedAsyncIterableIterator<ContainerItem, ServiceListContainersSegmentResponse> object.
This is the same code from the example for the blob-storage module, link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob
If you scroll down to the 'List the containers' section.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your are getting this error because your Node version is lower than 10.0 and doesn't support `for await...of`. <s>As a side note, `for await` has no effect here and can be substituted for just `for`</s> Turns out api does need it

---

added:
from the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob#list-the-containers): you can either use `for await of` if your runtime supports it, or iterate an iterable in an old-fashioned way

```
let containerItem = await result.next();
while (!containerItem.done) {
  console.log(`Container ${i++}: ${containerItem.value.name}`);
  containerItem = await iter.next();
}
```

Comment: If i remove the await after for it give me following error:
TypeError: result is not iterable
    at main (c:\Users\g.mohammed.taher\WebstormProjects\\azure-blob.js:8:33)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:696:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3

Comment: so, the result isn't iterable - i.e. `result` is probably not what you think it is @GhulamMohammedTaher - if I were you, I'd update the question with this new information

Comment: And the listContainer returns PagedAsyncIterableIterator<ContainerItem, ServiceListContainersSegmentResponse> object.

Comment: I guess Max is correct for...await is only available in node 10.0 version.

Comment: Thanks for your help Max and all those tried. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an work around for this one:

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

async function main() {
    try {
        const blobServiceClient = await BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=devappsstorage;AccountKey=aw/FF01OIfnYmK6Bh+d4NIhvVBaDKn942O22YAMNycX/27qKVwYW+/Dma/C7pI+lvU0wpo/VBJ1jFd4yi3MMWw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net');
        let i = 1;
        let iter = blobServiceClient.listContainers();
        let containerItem = await iter.next();
        while (!containerItem.done) {
            console.log(`Container ${i++}: ${containerItem.value.name}`);
            containerItem = await iter.next();
          }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

main();
```